# How do you get a timestamp in Arduino-ESP8266?

Tags: timestamp, esp8266, ntp, arduino-esp8266

I would like to get a timestamp with [Arduino-ESP8266](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino).

But I don't have any idea how to get that.

I suppose we have to get the time from the Internet since the ESP8266 doesn't have any clock. Do we need to do that only once or every time we need a timestamp?

I'm already connected by Wi-Fi to the Internet.

Comment: worth mentioning: you can can get a RTC module for under $1 shipped... http://www.ebay.com/itm/201577236297

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[NTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) is the proven way of getting time remotely. NTP libraries, like @Marcel denotes, is making [UDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) connections to a server with an interval. So you do not need to do any polling to the server before using it.

Here is the usage of an NTP library with a one-hour offset and one minute refresh interval:

```
#include <NTPClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>

#define NTP_OFFSET   60 * 60      // In seconds
#define NTP_INTERVAL 60 * 1000    // In miliseconds
#define NTP_ADDRESS  "europe.pool.ntp.org"

WiFiUDP ntpUDP;
NTPClient timeClient(ntpUDP, NTP_ADDRESS, NTP_OFFSET, NTP_INTERVAL);

void setup(){
  timeClient.begin();
}

void loop() {
  timeClient.update();
}
```

To get a timestamp or formatted time anytime you want, use the functions:

```
String formattedTime = timeClient.getFormattedTime();
unsigned long epcohTime =  timeClient.getEpochTime();
```

Comment: Thanks! I get an error at your 4th line : `error: 'WiFiUDP' does not name a type` Do I need another library for that ?

Comment: I added this: `#include <WiFiUdp.h>` and it's compiling

Comment: `timeClient.getFormattedTime();` = 00:04:49 when it's 12:46, how do I addjust this ? (I'm in europe Brussels)

Comment: You are right! I've just added the missing library to the answer. So, your offset is setting with NTP_OFFSET and it is in seconds! So we gave 120 seconds which i 2 minutes to the offset. I've corrected it with GMT+1 by setting 3600 which should be valid for Belgium.

Comment: @ooo Any results?

Comment: Still need `#include <WiFiUdp.h>`. This example works: https://github.com/arduino-libraries/NTPClient/blob/master/examples/Basic/Basic.ino  and is just 1 hour off

Comment: so I added `#define NTP_OFFSET  1*60*60 ` like you said. Thanks ! (I think your respons also misses `timeClient.begin();`)

Comment: also `unsigned long epcohTime =  getEpochTime();` is not working. I think you can remove it

Comment: Question : This gives me only the hh:mm:ss, I would also need the date. Is that possible too?

Comment: @ooo, thanks for your feedback. I did not like to share complete sketch, but if it is confusing, i'll update it of course. This NTP library has only a function in its public api which returns day number. It returns 0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday etc. If it is enough for you, use getDay() of the timeClient.

Comment: Is there a way to get Date?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at that code I don't think this microcontroller directly has a clock built in as mentioned. Since you have Wi-Fi though you could make a web query to get it instead.

I'd use a REST query to a place like this:

https://timezonedb.com/api

Which will give you back a JSON formatted time. If you only need accuracy +/- a few seconds that will be fine. You could lower the bandwidth / improve battery life by setting the time like this and then using an internal timer to calculate an offset instead of making a query every time you need a time stamp. Eventually you would need to requery the time and 'correct' it since your timer on that probably is not accurate for long periods of time, plus it could eventually roll over.

If you need the time more accurately then that you will likely need a clock. You could try to do a bit of correction based on ping, but all in all how accurate it needs to be is based on your project requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Contact a specific date/time API on the Internet [as described by user2927848](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40515177/how-do-you-get-a-timestamp-in-arduino-esp8266/40515642#40515642). Or send a simple HTTP request to a server you trust and read the [`Date`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Response_fields) response header.

If you need greater precision, you may want to use an [NTP client for Arduino](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/NTPclient).

Answer (score 1):

There is also another solution for ESP8266/ESP32. The Espressif's time implemenation provides a `configTime()` method which alows configuring and using a NTP server (see [SimpleTime.ino](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/ESP32/examples/Time/SimpleTime/SimpleTime.ino) example by Espressif).

*Assumption*:
You have already setup and connected to a WiFi network and UTP library is loaded.

First configure your timezone and NTP server f.e.:

```cpp
const char* ntpServer1 = "pool.ntp.org";
const char* ntpServer2 = "time.nist.gov";
const char* time_zone = "CET-1CEST,M3.5.0,M10.5.0/3"; // TimeZone rule for Europe/Berlin

configTime(time_zone, ntpServer1, ntpServer2);
```

After the time is fetched and set just call `time(nullptr)` you receive the current timestamp.